# amazon s3 variables not working in heroku environment rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

Hello I have included given code

```
def store_s3(file)
    # We create a connection with amazon S3
    AWS.config(access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'], secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'])
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET_LABELS']]
    object = bucket.objects[File.basename(file)]
    # the file is not the content of the file is the route
    # file_data = File.open(file, 'rb')
    object.write(file: file)
    # save the file and return an url to download it
    object.url_for(:read, response_content_type: 'text/csv')
  end
```

this code is working correctly in my local data is stored in amazon but when I had deployed code in heroku server I had made variables on server too.

[image]

is there anything which I am missing here please let me know cause of issue.

Comment: `I had made variables on server too` how?

Comment: I don't see `S3_BUCKET_LABELS` anywhere

Comment: Check heroku logs for exact errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't see region, in your example is S3_Hostname your region?
for myself, region was just like 'us-west-2'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup your s3 with carrierwave and gem fog you can do it like this on config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_directory = 'name for s3 directory'

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => 'your access key',
    :aws_secret_access_key => 'your secret key',
    :region => 'your region ex: eu-west-2'
  }
end
```